# How to dispose timer

Tags: c#

I have the following code which uses the System.Timers.Timer:

```
// an instance variable Timer inside a method
Timer aTimer = new Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
aTimer.Interval = 300000;
aTimer.AutoReset = false;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
while (aTimer.Enabled)
{
    if (count == expectedCount)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

And I have the following code to handle the event:

```
private static void OnElapsedTime(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

The question is: if the timer event gets triggered and enters the OnElapsedTime, would the Timer object stops and be properly garbage collected?  If not, what can I do to properly dispose of the Timer object/stop it?  I don't want the timer to suddenly creep up and cause havoc in my app.

Comment: `while (aTimer.Enabled)`... Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using a timer?

Comment: Well I just wanted to loop while the timer is still active.  The timer is really just a way for the system to wait for a certain amount of time.  Threads are not favoured in my context so I opted to use timer instead.

Comment: You're using a thread whether you like it or not.  Thread.Sleep seems like the way to go.  The code you have there is actually quite nasty performance-wise.

Comment: @Eric Mickelsen: I'm running the above code inside Sharepoint code. I'm not too sure how SharePoint will handle threads, hence I went for Timer instead.  If threads will provide better performance and neater code, I'll love to use it.

Comment: My point is that your code is already executing in a thread.  By using System.Timer, you're likely actually causing another thread to be used.  By using System.Threading, you're not.  So if your organization has some aversion to multi-threading, you are disobeying the spirit of the law in order to follow the letter of the law.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Call Timer.Dispose:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0225y6.aspx

```
private static void OnElapsedTime(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Timer)source).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: The disposal is a very good practice, however the timer should be properly garbaged when it's not more running. Anyway, before invoking the Dispose method, I'd unsubscribe the event handler: that will prevent further unexpected callbacks.

Answer (score 5):

You need not use `while` loop, `AutoReset = false` already make sure `Timer` trigger one time only.

Comment: Unless he's enabling it again in the event handler, which is quite common.